# How to throw an error by yourself in apache2?

Tags: php, html, apache2

so I'm wondering if it's possible to throw an error by yourself like a 451 or an 418 or a 406.

 It would be cool if it's possible.
Maybe in several ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant change them for sure!

but you can redirect them to another number like this :

```
Redirect 200 /404
```

or

```
Redirect 404 /200
```

Or to custom number, you created as a directory and has an index page in it. you can redirect to a custom page is well.

More on ask apache : [The htaccess Redirects](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument/#htaccess_Redirects)